# How to programmatically map URL to handler in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an xml file containing URLs. I would like to take those URLs and map them to a default handler from which I can return a ModelAndView object. If this is possible can anyone point me in the direction of how? Would this stop me from being able to use standard annotation driven handlers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement your own HandlerMapping. See here **[Is it possible to dynamically set RequestMappings in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758504/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-set-requestmappings-in-spring-mvc)**