# RequestMappingHandlerMapping afterPropertiesSet method results into ambigious mapping

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot, runtime, pf4j

I am trying to create an endpoint at runtime using the PF4J library. I have managed to load the Plugin with rest API functionality at boot time, but now I try to map the endpoint at runtime when the plugin gets installed at runtime. I have tried to use the afterPropertiesSet() method from the RequestMappingHandlerMapping object, but it seems that the existing endpoints from the core Spring Boot application gets overwritten/duplicated. However, the endpoints from the Plugin are working as they should. The endpoints from the core Spring Boot application does not seem to work.

This causes an ambiguous method of mapping error when trying to call the core endpoints. The stack trace can be found below.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8090/error': {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest), public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)}
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:986) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_71]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8090/error': {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest), public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)}
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:370) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:317) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:62) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:351) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1188) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
... 26 common frames omitted
```

And the code below is what I use to register the endpoints dynamically on runtime:

```
for (PluginWrapper plugin : startedPlugins) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "PluginID : " + plugin.getPluginId());
        extensionClassNames = pluginManager.getExtensionClassNames(plugin.getPluginId());
        for (String extensionClassName : extensionClassNames) {
            try {
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Extension class name :  " + extensionClassName);
                Class<?> extensionClass = plugin.getPluginClassLoader().loadClass(extensionClassName);
                beanFactory.registerSingleton(extensionClassName, extensionFactory.create(extensionClass));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    webApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.class)
            .forEach((k, v) -> v.afterPropertiesSet());
```

Basically, it just makes beans from the Plugin code that is being loaded (installed and started) and then it tries to map the endpoints with afterPropertiesSet() method

Sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39671540/9627948

Comment: I seemed to have solved it by first unregistering all the mappings and then invoking the afterPropertiesSet() method