# How to make this dynamic request mapping work on multiple hosts?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, distributed-computing, distributed-caching

In my spring application, I have support for dynamic paths using RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerMapping like the solution suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758504/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-set-requestmappings-in-spring-mvc).

This works when there is only one host serving all requests. But when there are multiple hosts in cluster serving the requests, the dynamic request mapping added to one host is not available in other hosts.

What is best solution to make this dynamic request mapping work on multiple hosts?