# Is it possible to set the value of RequestMapping as a string array defined in a properties file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to set a RequestMapping in a RestController to be for a number of patterns, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/value1/**", "/value2", "/value3", "/value4", "/value5"})
public ResponseEntity<String> processWithBody(@RequestBody String payload, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    return process(request, payload);
}
```

That works perfectly, but I would like to have the list of patterns taken from a property in a properties file.

I tried defining a property like so

```
request.mapping=/value1/**, /value2, /value3, /value4, /value5
```

and then updating the code to reference it

```
@RequestMapping(value = { Constants.REQUEST_MAPPING })
public ResponseEntity<String> proxyWithBody(@RequestBody String payload, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    return proxy(request, payload);
}
```

However it no longer cause my method to be called.  I have tried various versions of the definition but nothing works.  Is this possible?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Sounds more like a design problem if one method handles so many different specific paths.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping-properties-file
Does this help?

Comment: That article only shows dealing with a single path not an array of paths so doesn't assist.

Comment: The design is fine for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can get part of the path as a parameter - @PathVariable("id") String id.
And in the code, check if "id" matches the set in "request.mapping"

```
@RequestMapping("/{id1}")
public ResponseEntity<String> proxyWithBody1(@RequestBody String payload, @PathVariable("id1") String id1, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    // check id
    return proxy(request, payload);
}

@RequestMapping("/{id1}/{id2}")
public ResponseEntity<String> proxyWithBody2(@RequestBody String payload, @PathVariable("id1") String id1, @PathVariable("id2"), String id2, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    // check id
    return proxy(request, payload);
}

// "/{id1}/{id2}/..."
```

Then:

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
public ResponseEntity<String> proxyWithBody(@RequestBody String payload, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String id[] = request.getRequestURI().split("/+");
    // check id
    return proxy(request, payload);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help as the first part of the path is different in each case, so no generic "api" part.

Comment: Fixed it, but for other depths more method will be needed

Comment: I don't know how many depths there will be.  I am writing something to proxy requests to other services, and had hoped to be able to specify the paths as a property that would mean if a new value was required a redeploy of the property file and a restart of the service would handle it, rather than have to make a code change.

Comment: Or we intercept everything and parse the path manually: request.getRequestURI().split("/+")

Comment: I did consider that but it seems a bit messy.  I was hoping that the property route would be possible, as it is possible by manually specifying the String array.

Comment: Maybe the solution is here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758504/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-set-requestmappings-in-spring-mvc